# create catsearch index for comma delimited values in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have several columns in oracle tables that contain "error codes"

```
ID   DESC   ERROR_CODE
=========================
01   ITM1   01,03,06
02   ITM2   04,05,16
03   ITM3   00,15
```

At the moment, there are a lot of queries that use `LIKE %05%`

Is it possible to construct an index in oracle that will parse out all the "words" between the commas, and then use `CATSEARCH` to search, so that the values can be indexed?

Often multiple error codes are being filtered out of the results.

```
WHERE ERROR_CODE NOT LIKE '%05%'
AND ERROR_CODE NOT LIKE '%15%'
AND ERROR_CODE NOT LIKE '%10%'
```

I would like to improve the performance of these filter queries.
The system is legacy, and I cannot redesign the data, at least not for now.

Comment: Are all your error codes two characters?

Comment: yes, always two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried creating and tuning your own lexer with desired parameters? ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cdatadic.htm#i1007615)) Maybe something like this can work for your case: (not tested)

```
begin 
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('comma_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'WHITESPACE', ',');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'NUMGROUP', '#'); 
end; 
/

create index node_sequence_index 
  on error_table(error_code) 
  indextype is ctxsys.ctxcat 
  parameters ('lexer comma_lexer')
;
```

The arbitrary `#` replaces the default `NUMGROUP` of `,` so it won't count  the error sequence e.g. `150,020,030` as one number.

The index type is `ctxsys.ctxcat` to optimize index for `CATSEARCH`.

Comment: FYI: you don't need to draw attention to your edits if you're just improving your answer.

Comment: Noted, should've added it to the edit notes probably

Comment: Yes, that's what they're for :)